# Moving files to other harddrive

Tags: linux

I installed Linux Mint yesterday and so far everything is working fine, except when I installed Linux Mint, I chose: "Install alongside Windows 10". So I assume it was installed on the same harddrive as my Windows 10: my SSD Which is fine, but, how can I make everything else such as all programs and such I install, is moved to another partion that I made on my HDD?

I only have 5 gb available in "my computer". I need to keep the OS where it is and move everything like file downloads and installations and all those kind of things, to the new partion in my HDD.

could someone suggest how I can change this, thank you in advance

Comment: You need to share more details of your hdd, total capacity of the drive, the partitions you made etc. so we could help.

Comment: on my hdd I have 400 gb free and I made a new 50gb partion with GParted, I would like that new partion to contain everything of my Linux Mint except the OS itself

Comment: like I'm downloading new programs righttt now and I almost have run out of space, how can I make everything go to the new partion instead of the 10gb space the OS is located at?

Comment: Most of the operating system gets installed to /usr, most of the software you manually install also go to /usr.   In the GNU/Linux world there is not such a strong border between operating system and user applications.  It should however be possible to move /usr to a different partition, but this will also move large parts of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to move directories from the ssd to the hdd and then mount them to the original location (automounted). Like `mv /home/me/bigdata /path/to/hdd-partition` and recreate the folder as mount point `mkdir /home/me/bigdata` then add a line to /etc/fstab to mount `/path/to/hdd-partition/bigdata` to `/home/me/bigdata`

But beware: If you do this with some folder like `/usr` it can ruin your system if mounting fails.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply, im very new to linux, I don't understand where should I do this? should I put those commands in the console and it will work? edit: to add, when you say /bigdata, is that a placeholder for what you mean I would like to move? I would like as much data as possible to be on my HDD, and only OS on SSD so OS load squickly

Comment: it seems like everything is a little laggy maybe beacuse of the space

Comment: Okay, sorry for rushing in. If your not familiar with the file system and mounting, I suggest you should either ask someone more experienced to perform this with you or just move certain big, but uncritical directories to the hdd. I don't dare to give you some codelines without complete knowledge of your system. Meanwhile, the introduction of shirish is good to read for you.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : this will take quite a bit of time to understand.

The thing to understand is that Linux or preferably GNU/Linux behaves a little differently than what you are used to.

This is from memory, What is C:\Programs and C:\Program Settings or whatever is called all lives under `/` or what we call root or system space. Just hang on to the terms for now.

/home is where all your data lives, all your movies, songs and your preferences about how programs should behave live.

What some people do is they would make three partitions when you are installing any GNU/Linux distribution.

/ - is for number of applications or programs that you want and that entirely depends on if you want to explore applications or if you have a limited set of applications that you want to play with. For instance in servers / may be pretty limited but other partitions would be larger.

I'm sharing how I have done for one fun/experimental desktop that I use.

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~] - [10083]
└─[$] df -h /dev/sda*                                                                                                                
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
/dev/sda6       184G   61G  114G  35% /
/dev/sda7        92G   87G  590M 100% /home
/dev/sda8       541G  512G  1.4G 100% /data
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
```

If you look at mine you would see I made three partitions, ' /dev/sda6 for / ' '/dev/sda7 for /home' and '/dev/sda8 for /data' which is where all my big data i.e. movies, music live. There is also another partition called swap which you can see below .

```
[$] free -m                                                                                                                        
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1994        1464          73         116         457         262
Swap:          5099         829        4270
```

So if you want the best performance for your system, I would suggest to reformat the GNU/Linux partitions like this -

Put / and swap in your SSD . To share about swap simply, its like an extension to your memory (RAM) but using your hdd/sdd. If you put / and swap in SSD, it should make the laggines go away to a large extent.

Now you need to figure out where your hdd and sdd are mounted. For instance, I have an hdd and an external hdd mounted. There is a command called mount which tells me which is mounted where.

```
[$] mount | grep /dev/sd

/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda8 on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/shirish/Seagate-Slim-Backup type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

As can be seen all /dev/sda drives are hdd drives, while the /dev/sdb1 drive is my external hdd drive. It's very much possible that your sdd might be mounted as either /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1, something like that.

I would recommend either you use the distribution installer or or Gparted to do as shared above. Once you understand the above, then you can use what Philipos has shared as well. I would urge you to write all your steps on a piece of paper so you know what you are doing and adapt whatever we are sharing to how things are stacked on your system. Because we don't have your system, all what we know is based on guesses only.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may disappoint you, but the thing is that you can't separate user installed programs from the operating system.

If you start the Synaptic package manager, you'll notice that there are many packages already installed.  A few of these you can consider to be "pre-installed programs", but many of them are parts of the operating system.
It's just a bunch of packages that are more or less important than other and may depend on other packages, but there is no distinction between "user programs" and "operating system".

Most of the "operating system" packages will be installed in /usr and practically all "user program" packages will be installed there too.

You'll have to move the entire /usr to the HDD, it should be pretty much like you did with /home.  Note: it needs a different partition than home.

But, it is probably easier and safer to just reinstall Mint and select "Manual" instead of "Install alongside Windows".  It SHOULD be safe to use the already existing home partition, but always make a backup first.

It shouldn't be <del>too</del> slow with /usr on the HDD.   So maybe you could even consider having only one partition (on the HDD of course) for simplicity?

But if you insist on faster booting and you you choose the easier and safer method, it MIGHT just be possible to do what you want: keeping some of the stuff in /usr on the SSD.  But this will require knowing exactly what those parts are, and how much space they will need and how much they might grow because they all need their own partitions.

**@Anyone** who knows which parts are the bottleneck when booting Mint should edit my answer and create a "table" of what to put on the HDD and what to put on the SSD and how large the partitions should be.